# pyodbc import error with mac M1, Os version monterey

Tags: python, pyodbc, importerror, apple-m1, dlopen

I have installed pyodbc but unable to import it.

python 3.8.10
Mac OS Monterey, M1 chip

```
>>> import pyodbc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen({env_path}env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyodbc.cpython-38-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_SQLAllocHandle'
>>>
```

if any one has any solutions please post.

I tried installing pyodbc using brew, installed unixodbc also.
tried installing using `pip install --no-binary :all: pyodbc`
none of the above approach worked.

Comment: Hey Ashish, have you found a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved for me on MacOS Ventura 13.2 in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75190318/4922810) answer, but using `pip3` instead of pip. To reiterate (with `pip3`):

1. Uninstall pyodbc:

```
pip3 uninstall pyodbc
```

2. Install it again, but compiled locally:

```
pip3 install --no-binary :all: pyodbc
```

As mentioned in the linked answer, make sure that unixodbc is installed. Using brew:

```
brew install unixodbc
```