# How can I import pyodbc to connect to filemaker odbc? cpython-310-darwin.so is not working

Tags: python, odbc, pyodbc, filemaker

I've been banging my head against the wall for a few days on this and none of the troubleshooting is working. I tried the link below but still getting that same error.

[Unable to import pyodbc on Apple Silicon - Symbol not found: _SQLAllocHandle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66731036/unable-to-import-pyodbc-on-apple-silicon-symbol-not-found-sqlallochandle)

```html
    import pyodbc
ImportError: dlopen({env}/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyodbc.cpython-310-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _SQLAllocHandle
  Referenced from: {env}/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyodbc.cpython-310-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in {env}/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyodbc.cpython-310-darwin.so
```

I reinstalled the driver
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-1-configure-development-environment-for-pyodbc-python-development?view=sql-server-ver16

this does nothing.
pip install --pre --no-binary :all: pyodbc

Can anyone help or recommend and alternative option to connect to a filemaker odbc connection?